# Cordova does not build. Res folder does not exist under platform\android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

I am building ionic app. After the ionic and cordova update I started having issues. I am trying to build the android platform but I got the following error:

```
cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file 
(code=ENOENT):PROJECT_PATH\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml

 Parsing PROJECT_PATH\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml failed
(node:13716) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise 
rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, 
open 'PROJECT_PATH\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml'
```

- cordova version: 8.0.0
- ionic version: 3.19.0
- installed android platform: android 7.0.0

Comment: cordova-android 7 changed the folder structure. You must have a hook or plugin writing on the wrong side. You will have to find which one is causing that, or downgrade the platform to cordova-android 6.4.0

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I downgraded to cordova-android 6.4.0 and everything is working now. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

For this platform android 7.0.0 or higher you have to change "res/" to "app/src/main/res/"

Comment: Please share where you have to change those parameters.

Comment: Hi @dariru, can you tell me more about your issue?

Comment: I also have the same problem when cordova-android 7.0.0 and cordova 8.0.0. I was wondering where or which file you have to change "res/" to "app/src/main/res".

Comment: How do you change it? Can you kindly elaborate more as I know this is an auto-generate folder when add new platform.. Thanks